# Java 8 getOrDefault method on HashMap not working as expected

Tags: java, hashmap

I cannot figure out why this hashmap routine is not adding up counts on my characters as expected.  I suspect it has something to do with the cast between Character and char, but I'm not certain.  The count is always 1 for every character.

```
String s = "loveleetcode";

Map<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); 

for (int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++) {
    hm.put(s.charAt(x), hm.getOrDefault(hm.get(s.charAt(x)), 0) +1);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to change the line;

```
hm.put(s.charAt(x), hm.getOrDefault(hm.get(s.charAt(x)), 0) +1);
```

to

```
hm.put(s.charAt(x), hm.getOrDefault(s.charAt(x), 0) +1);
```

In the original code `hm.get(s.charAt(x))` will return `null`, and that key will not be present. Although the `null` is typed as an `Integer`, `Map.getOrDefault` (or indeed `get`) accepts `Object` for that argument, as that makes the `Map` interface work better with Java's bounded generics.

`char` can be autoboxed to `Character` just fine. `Character` can autounbox to `char` so long as it is not `null`.

Comment: Thank you.  I was just looking at it wrong.  Basically trying to do a double get.

Answer (score 0):

You use `hm.get(s.charAt(x)` it will always result in `null` because the entry key `s.char(x)` has not been put yet. Change it to:

```
hm.put(s.charAt(x), hm.getOrDefault(s.charAt(x), 0) + 1);
```

Moreover, I prefer a more self-explanatory approach using `computeIfPresent` and `putIfAbsent`:

```
hm.computeIfPresent(s.charAt(x), (ch, i) -> ++i); // if the key is present, increment the value
hm.putIfAbsent(s.charAt(x), 1);                   // if the key is not present, put with value 1
```

... or use Stream API and `Collectors.groupingBy` with `Collectors.counting` that is suitable for this kind of tasks:

```
Map<Character, Long> hm = s.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char) i)         // Stream<Character>
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(  // Map<Character, Long>
                                           Function.identity(),     // ... key is preserved
                                           Collectors.counting())); // ... total count
```